# PySpark3 - Reading XML files

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to read an XML file in my PySpark3 Jyupter notebook (running in Azure).

I have this code:

`df = spark.read.load("wasb:///data/test/Sample Data.xml")`

However I keep getting the error `java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file`:

```
An error occurred while calling o616.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 43, wn2-xxxx.cloudapp.net, executor 2): java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=wasb://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/data/test/Sample Data.xml; isDirectory=false; length=6947; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}
```

I know its reaching the file - from looking at the length - matches the xml file size - but stuck after that?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the two blogs below, I think they can answer your question completely.

1. [Azure Blob Storage with Pyspark](https://luminousmen.com/post/azure-blob-storage-with-pyspark)
2. [Reading JSON, CSV and XML files efficiently in Apache Spark](https://szczeles.github.io/Reading-JSON-CSV-and-XML-files-efficiently-in-Apache-Spark/)

The code is like as below.

```
session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

session.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
    "<your-storage-account-access-key>"
)
# OR SAS token for a container:
# session.conf.set(
#    "fs.azure.sas.<container-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
#    "<sas-token>"
# )

# your Sample Data.xml file in the virtual directory `data/test`
df = session.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .options(rowTag="book").load("wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/data/test/")
```

If you were using Azure Databricks, I think the code will works as expected. otherwise, may you need to install the `com.databricks.spark.xml` library in your Apache Spark cluster.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the step-by-step instructions I followed to resolve this issue.

**Step 1)** Install the XML package in the Apache Spark

You can download the JAR from the below link.
https://libraries.io/maven/com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12
Instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-pool-packages#manage-packages-from-synapse-studio-or-azure-portal

**Step 2)** Grant “Storage Blob data contributor” access to the user for the container under IAM

[image: IAM]

**Step 3)** Run the notebook by creating dataframe using the below script

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.read \
    .format("xml") \
    .option("rowTag", "xml tag name here") \
    .load('abfss://<container name>@<storage account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path of the xml file>/file.xml)')

display(df)
```

Data frame should be displayed.